# Fuzzy substring search in O(N log N)

Tags: algorithm, string-search

I have two strings s1 and s2. I need to find substring in s1 with the length of s2 that has most symbols matching to s2. Both string have length less or equal than N. How would I do it in O(N log N) worst-case time?

Edit:
More formal definition of problem. For two given strings s1, s2 find such K, that len(s1)>len(s2)+K-1 and f(K) is maximum, where f(n) is defined by

f(n) = |{j : s1[K+j]==s2[j]}|

Comment: What does "closest match" mean?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, maximum number of matching symbols.

Comment: Does the order of the symbols matter? Or just which symbols are present?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: @templatetypedef order matters. See definition I added.

Comment: @DanielWagner Article you are referring to only works for consequtive substring match. And has essentially O(n^2) complexity.

Comment: @LevK. "Substring" means consecutive. For non-consecutive, the term you want is "subsequence"; in which case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: @DanielWagner I need substring that is as close to a perfect match as possible, but is not necessarily perfect. That also means the solution exist for any s1 and s2. See definition I added to question.

Comment: AFAICT, you don't want to consider insertions or deletions, which means you're looking for a substring that minimises the Hamming (not Levenshtein) distance.  There's a (somewhat surprising) FFT-based algorithm for doing this efficiently, though it takes time proportional to the alphabet size.  See my answer in the link for the close-as-dupe vote.

Comment: ... which doesn't seem to be showing up, so here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146026/fastest-way-to-find-minimal-hamming-distance-to-any-substring